# Need Help on Mousemove event in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, mousemove

I am creating a side menu for my database which uses mousemove event on buttons. When the mouse pointer hovers over the button it change backcolor, forecolor and backstyle. I used the following code:

```
Private Sub ProductBtn_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

Me.ProductBtn.BackStyle = 1
Me.ProductBtn.BackColor = RGB(164, 213, 226)
Me.ProductBtn.ForeColor = RGB(0, 114, 188)

End Sub
```

(Note: Button's back style is set to transparent)

The following happened when I tried on a button....

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem is when I remove the mouse pointer over the button it doesn't go back to normal or reset to default (like the first image). How do I do it? Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `HoverColor` and `HoverForeColor` like this example:

```vb
Public Sub StyleCommandButtons(ByRef frm As Form)

' Apply a style to all non-transparent command buttons on a form.
' 2014-10-10. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' Version 1.0.0
' License: MIT.

' Requires:
'   Module:
'       ModernThemeColours

' Typical usage:
'
'   Private Sub Form_Load()
'       Call StyleCommandButtons(Me)
'   End Sub

    Dim ctl                 As Control
    
    For Each ctl In frm.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acCommandButton Then
            If ctl.Transparent = True Then
                ' Leave transparent buttons untouched.
            Else
                ctl.Height = 454
                ctl.UseTheme = True
                If ctl.Default = True Then
                    ctl.BackColor = wpThemeColor.Cobalt
                Else
                    ctl.BackColor = ctl.Parent.Section(ctl.Section).BackColor
                End If
                ctl.HoverForeColor = ctl.BackColor
                ctl.HoverColor = wpThemeColor.White
                ctl.PressedColor = wpThemeColor.Darken
                ctl.BorderWidth = 2
                ctl.BorderStyle = 1
                ctl.BorderColor = wpThemeColor.White
                ctl.ForeColor = wpThemeColor.White
                ctl.FontName = "Segoe UI"
                ctl.FontSize = 11
                ctl.FontBold = True
                ctl.FontItalic = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    Set ctl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also: [VBA.ModernBox](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernBox)

Comment: Can I change colors to my liking?

Comment: Certainly. That's a question of preferences. In this example, the goal was to stick with the great _Windows Phone Color Theme_.